# Plugin CSS not enqueing

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode, css, wp-enqueue-style

## My apologies if there is an answer to this already making this a duplicate question, I have spend the last 3 days trying to get the CSS styling to be applied in a way that WordPress would allow, it is very likely I have started going 'code-blind'

I am working on a plugin to display user-generated content and an average rating of a service provided.
The data all comes in from an XML file hosted elsewhere and everything is working great!
Now when I wanted to release the plugin to WordPress so others could use it, I had to make some changes to the code, they wouldn't let me use `<style>` and `<link>` tags for the CSS.

Some of the options in the CSS are based on user settings that they've setup in the options page for the plugin, I've tried several ways of getting it to work but it just won't load the styling properly.

Because of the settings a user can make I have made the CSS files into PHP files (this way I could keep it all in the same place).

In the main plugin file I have the following lines:
`add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'kvssm_enqueue_styles' );` I have tried this with `wp_enqueue_scripts` as well to the same result of the styling not being applied.

The function being called:

```
function kvssm_enqueue_styles(  ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reviewCSS', plugins_url( '/review-style.php', __FILE__ ), array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'widgetCSS', plugins_url( '/widget-style.php', __FILE__ ), array(), null );
}
```

I have tried several itterations of this function, with and without `wp_register_style`

The last method I've attempted was in the css.php to add the following lines:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/css' );
header( 'Cache-control: must-revalidate' );

include( 'ssm-klantenvertellen.php' );

$dir       = kvssm_get_directory(  );
$kvOptions = kvssm_get_options_kvssm(  );
$pvOptions = kvssm_get_options_pvssm(  );
?>
```

I am trying to apply the CSS as follows:

```
color: <?php echo $kvOptions[ 'kvssm_color_field_2' ]; ?>;
```

However this last method won't work because of a Fatal error the include causes, add_action is not recognized as a function, the only reason I use the `include` is for the functions to fetch the settings I need, if I place these functions inside the `css.php` instead it still causes fatal errors, this time because of the `plugins_url()` not being recognized.

The three functions:

```
function kvssm_get_directory(  ) {
    $dir     = plugins_url( __DIR__ );
    $dirA    = explode( 'public_html', $dir );
    $dir     = $dirA[ 1 ];
    return $dir;
}

function kvssm_get_options_kvssm(  ) {
    $options = get_option( 'kvssm_settings' );
    return $options;
}

function kvssm_get_options_pvssm(  ) {
    $options = get_option( 'pvssm_settings' );
    return $options;
}
```

Does anyone know how I should setup the CSS in order for it to be displayed properly? Some features that might be of importance:

- The plugin adds a shortcode
- The shortcode returns a result which should have the CSS attached to it
- The settings page in the back-end includes a preview of the shortcode using `do_shortcode()`

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style` does not accept php files as source. Only css files.

Comment: Thank you, I changed `wp_enqueue_style` to `wp_enqueue_script` it adds the basic CSS now but the dynamic settings still dont get applied, doing it via the include still results in the same errors, placing the functions inside the style.php still results in an error about the plugins_url function

Comment: So you need to generate dynamic css in admin panel or in front end?

Comment: The settings for the dynamic css are in the admin panel, i want it to display in the result of the shortcode which is on the front-end, the admin panel has a preview of the result by using the shortcode, i assume just the front-end will also display it using that preview section.

Comment: Something fun I've just realized:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'widgetCSS', plugins_url( '/widget-style.php', __FILE__ ), array(), null );` Displays the static CSS in the admin panel, no CSS in the front-end, `wp_enqueue_script( 'reviewCSS', plugins_url( '/review-style.php', __FILE__ ), array(), null );` Doesn't display any CSS in the admin panel nor the front-end

Comment: Because you have hook it in `admin_enqueue_scripts`, right? The hook for front end is `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: ..that makes a lot of sense yes, sorry. Not sure if it's the right way to do things, but I've added a hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` now as well for the same function.

Comment: It's not a problem to hook the same function to different hooks. What bothers me is the way you generating your css. Why don't you just echo a css style inside `wp_head` or `admin_head`?

Comment: That would require the use of <style> tags, correct? I've been told by an email from WordPress that I'm not allowed to use <style> (or <link>) tags in the code.

Comment: Oh really? Sorry you mentioned it in your question. I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add inline CSS, use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style).

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 257470
 * Description: WordPress StackExchange question 257470
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257470/
 * Author: Nathan Johnson
 * Licence: GPL2+
 * Licence URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html
 */

//* Don't access this file directly
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die();

if( ! class_exists( 'wpse_257470' ) ):
  class wpse_257470 {
    public function plugins_loaded() {
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ] );
    }

    public function wp_enqueue_scripts() {
      //* It's necessary to have a 'base' CSS file that we can attach to
      wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse-257470', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'style.css' );
      $color = '#257470';
      $custom_css = ".custom_color { color: $color };";
      wp_add_inline_style( 'wpse-257470', $custom_css );
    }
  }
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ new wpse_257470(), 'plugins_loaded' ] );
endif;
```

Comment: `wp_add_inline_style` seems to have done the trick! Thank you so much. Now I just have to hope WordPress accepts the method and there's no other issues with the code according to them.